# How to display all images in a directory with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to display all images from a particular directory in static (static/plots).  Here is my python:

```
hists = os.listdir('static/plots')
hists = ['plots/' + file for file in hists]
return render_template('report.html', hists = hists)
```

and my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE=html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Store Report
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    {{first_event}} to {{second_event}}
    {% for hist in hists %}
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{{hist}}')}}" alt="{{hist}}">
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>`
```

And when the template successfully renders, the templates are not fetched.  Opening the image in a new tab yields: 
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/%7B%7Bhist%7D%7D`

I imagine the problem is with this line, but I can't figure out what's correct:

`<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{{hist}}')}}" alt="{{hist}}">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the line to this:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename=hist)}}" alt="{{hist}}">
```

You had an extra set of `{{ }}` in there which was rendering as `%7B` and `%7D`.

Comment: So basically anytime you're inside {{ }} flask knows what everything it knows about means? Let me know if my wording here was confusing

Comment: Yes, since you were already in {{ }} Flask can interpret the variable `hist`.

Answer (score 3):

I acheived success with this line:

```
<img src="static/{{hist}}" alt="{{hist}}">
```

I may have had an extra 'plots/' in here when I tried it before.